# Why does this loop, which is part of a Minimax statement, fail with the `if` condition added?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, for-loop, connect-four

I'm working on a Connect Four game with Minimax: https://codepen.io/acchang/pen/XWePpWB

I'm stuck on the first portion of the Minimax, which is to build a function that would prioritize moves that result in three tokens in a row.

I think I’m almost there, but I can’t figure out why the loop in `function scorePositionHoriz()` is shutting down on me after just evaluating the first position.

It works when I comment out the `if` condition and loops through the entire array `parallelBoard`. But when I uncomment the `if`, the javascript console shows me the loop shuts down after one attempt.

Below are the two critical functions. Can you say why the `for` loop is shutting down with the `if` condition and is there another way to do it?

````
function scorePositionHoriz (board, player) {
    for (let r=0; r<6; r++) {
        for (let c=0; c<4; c++) {
            (console.log("checking: " + (board[r][c]),(board[r][c+1]),(board[r][c+2])))
            // if ((board[r][c] == player) && (board[r][c+1] == player) && (board[r][c+2] == player)) {
            //     score = score + 10
            //     console.log("scored is" + score)
            //     return score
            // }
            // else (console.log("no matches: " + (board[r][c]),(board[r][c+1]),(board[r][c+2])))
            // return 0

            // also tried:
            // if ((Number.isInteger(board[r][c]) == Number.isInteger(board[r][c+1])) &&
            // (Number.isInteger(board[r][c+1]) == Number.isInteger(board[r][c+2]))) {
            //     console.log("equal true")}
            //  else (console.log("no matches: " + (board[r][c]),(board[r][c+1]),(board[r][c+2])))
            // return 0

            // something about "if" throwing things off
        }
    }
};

function pickBestMove() {
    let bestScore = -1
    let bestColumn 
    let parallelAvailable = findAvailableSpots(parallelBoard)

     for (s=0; s<parallelAvailable.length; s++) {
            let i;
            let j = parseInt(parallelAvailable[s] - 1)
            console.log ("from avail spot " + j)
            for (i = 5; i > -1; i--) 
                if (Number.isInteger(parallelBoard[i][j])) {
                parallelBoard[i].splice((j), 1, whosPlaying())
                break
            }
        let positionScore = scorePositionHoriz (parallelBoard, whosPlaying())
        console.log("test board with marker in " + gameboard[i][j])
        parallelBoard[i].splice((j), 1, gameboard[i][j])

        if (positionScore > bestScore) {
         bestScore = positionScore
        console.log("Best Score is " + bestScore)
        bestColumn = s
        }
        else {console.log("not better")}
        console.log("tested avail spot: " + s)
        }
        console.log("BestColumn decided: " + bestColumn)
        if (bestColumn == 0){
            let altSpot = (availableSpots[Math.floor(Math.random() * availableSpots.length)] - 1)
            console.log("random choice:" + altSpot)
            return altSpot
        }
    else {return bestColumn}
}```
````

Comment: _"but I can’t figure out why the loop in `function scorePositionHoriz()`"_ - There's no such function definition in your question. Only a call of that function (`scorePositionHoriz (parallelBoard, whosPlaying())`) -> [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) -> [mcve]

Comment: sorry, I'm an idiot -- usually I'm at my wits end when I write these questions, I should be more careful. I mistakenly deleted this at the top of the code block: `function scorePositionHoriz (board, player) {` ... but when I click "Edit(1)" I can't seem to get in. I'll keep trying.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's nothing to do with the `if`; it's the unconditional `return 0;` statement after the `else` block.

When your code reaches the first iteration of the two `for` loops, it either executes `return score;` or `return 0;`. That exits the current function, and no further iterations of your loops will be performed.

Reformatting your code should make it clearer:

```js
if ((board[r][c] == player) && (board[r][c+1] == player) && (board[r][c+2] == player)) {
    score = score + 10
    console.log("scored is" + score)
    return score; // Function exits here; loops are terminated
}
else {
    (console.log("no matches: " + (board[r][c]),(board[r][c+1]),(board[r][c+2])));
}

return 0; // Function exits here; loops are terminated
```

Comment: Yes! Thank you so much. That did it. I feel like I always keep digging and digging deeper in the same area, when I should just move a little bit over. "D'oh" indeed!